# I get the error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException while using AsyncTask (parse json data with gson)

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, gson, android-networking

I want to get json data and parse them through gson. I am able to do the correct parsing, but for one example that I did, I got this error:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

I know that using `internet` on UI thread is not allowed.
My example is simple:
In `onCreate` of the activity is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    kategoriListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.kategoriListView);

    new GetPlacesAsync().execute(placesUrl);
}
```

And on the AsyncTask:

```
class GetPlacesAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream doInBackground(String... params) {

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url = params[0];
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {

            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
                return null;
            }

            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            return getResponseEntity.getContent();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error for URL " + url, e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
        super.onPostExecute(inputStream);

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try
        {
            PlacesContainer places = gson.fromJson(reader, PlacesContainer.class);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Integer.toString(places.getCountPlaces()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, places.message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("READ_PLACES_ERROR", e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

My error is on the lines where I have used `try` `catch` block.

Comment: Indeed, this was not a duplicate - marking questions as such requires reading more than just the title.  In this case, the fact that reading the input stream can be a network operation was a subtlety that was being overlooked - while the idea that one shouldn't do network operations on the main thread was already well reflected in the intention of the code.

Comment: @Chris I didn't know that reading stream is a network operation. I thought that it is like using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: It is or isn't depending if reading from the stream means reading from the network - that's a key part of what makes this a legitimately non-duplicate question.  You needed to accomplish all the actual acquisition of data from the underlying network APIs in the background, and pass on a result.

Comment: @chris It is better to pas as a return value or to use a variable in AsyncTask class (that i can acces from both `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onPostExecute in executed on the UI thread.

Read your InputStream in doInBackground.

Comment: Thank you, I just returned json String instead of InputStream and it worked.

Comment: I have an object  of type `PlaceContainer` containing a list of `Places`. I want to get the data for places. It is better to return value from `doInBackground` or to create a variable in `AsyncTask` class and to populate in `doInBackground` then to use it on `onPostExecute`?

Comment: Both will work, but returning the value as doInBackground is slightly better because simpler (and AsyncTask is designed to be used this way).